# Local gem failed on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to customize the `haml-rails` gem,

So I fork it to my project on Github ,

Then clone to my local machine and tried to include it.

But it failed.

I fixed by `bundle update` , But I don't know why it succeeded by using `git`, because I thought they are two identical project.

Should I just change the `Gemfile` under the `haml-rails` if I  use `rails 3.2` and `railties 3.x` ? Or I should checkout the previous version of `haml-rails` which only support rails 3 ?

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    railties (3.2.13)

  In Gemfile:
    haml-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.1) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
~/sandbox/la
$ cat Gemfile | grep haml
#gem "haml-rails"
gem "haml-rails", :path => "/Users/hsu-wei-cheng/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails"
# gem "haml-rails", :git => 'git@github.com:poc7667/haml-rails.git'
~/sandbox/la
$ cd /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails
~/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails
(feature/custom_view_for_dqa)$ tree -L 3
.
├── Appraisals
├── Gemfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── gemfiles
│   ├── rails_4_0.gemfile
│   └── rails_4_1.gemfile
├── haml-rails.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── generators
│   │   └── haml
│   ├── haml-rails
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── haml-rails.rb
└── test
    ├── fixtures
    │   └── routes.rb
    ├── lib
    │   └── generators
    └── test_helper.rb

9 directories, 12 files
~/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails
(feature/custom_view_for_dqa)$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Installing activesupport (4.0.2)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Installing actionpack (4.0.2)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Installing actionmailer (4.0.2)
Installing activemodel (4.0.2)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Installing activerecord (4.0.2)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Installing appraisal (0.5.2)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using haml (4.0.5)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Installing railties (4.0.2)
Using haml-rails (0.5.3) from source at /Users/Hsu-Wei-Cheng/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using sprockets (2.10.1)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Installing rails (4.0.2)
Your bundle is updated!
~/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails
(feature/custom_view_for_dqa)$ bundle update
~/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails
(feature/custom_view_for_dqa)$ ls
Appraisals          LICENSE             gemfiles/           test/
Gemfile             README.md           haml-rails.gemspec
Gemfile.lock        Rakefile            lib/
~/Dropbox/Ruby/haml-rails
(feature/custom_view_for_dqa)$
```

Comment: Please remove the images, and replace them with the actual text you're seeing. Images actually hurt the usefulness of your question because they can't be searched, meaning fewer people can find them when looking for the answer to similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correctly, the older version of *haml-rails* gem depends on the *railites* gem *3.2.14*, the version the *haml-rails* gem, which is placed in the specfied folder depends on the *railites* gem *4.0.1*. So you have either to:

1. Remove the **Gemfile** and upgade all the *Rails* to *4.x* version. In most case this solution will take many time to fix, and is inappropriate.
2. Set the HEAD of the *haml-rails* gem placed on the path, to a *tag* or a *commit* that belongs to a version *3.2.13*, make a new branch, and work on the gem locally:

   ```
   cd /path/to/gem/haml-rails
   git reset --hard <commit or tag>
   git branch your_branch
   git checkout your_branch
   # do something with the code
   ```

   Specify in yuor **Gemfile** the following:

   ```
   gem 'haml-rails', :path => '/path/to/gem/haml-rails', :branch => 'your_branch'
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.Should I just change the `Gemfile` under the `haml-rails` if I  use `rails 3.2` and `railties 3.x` ? Or I should checkout the previous version of `haml-rails` which only support rails 3 ?

Comment: `git reset --hard 90dc86fa07e54ae9d56a202cf078f88b61a5cf5a` I ran the command and back to the previous version which only requires `s.add_dependency "railties",      [">= 3.1", "< 4.1"]`. Then developing under based on this version. did you mean it ? thanks

Comment: @poc yes I meant exactly this,you shell to develop on an other barnch based on the version, this is correct.